# Avoiding setting with copy warning

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_n_years = df.iloc[:, -self.num_years - 1:-1]
df_n_years.rename(columns=lambda x: 'VAL_' + str(x), inplace=True)  # results in SettingWithCopyWarning
```

I am extracting the last few columns from a dataframe and then renaming them. It does result in a setting with copy warning. I understand why the warning is happening, what's the best way to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
df_n_years = df_n_years.rename(columns=lambda x: 'VAL_' + str(x))
```

Comment: does doing iloc copy a part of dataframe into a new one? or is it just a view?

Comment: It is a view.  You can append `.copy()` if you want a copy.